# Problems with command make

Tags: makefile, command

I want to install CD-HIT but 'make' command shows error.

I am running in cygwin (32 bits) so I installed 'make' with apt.cyg and it seems to be correctly installed. Also, I've added the path where CD-HIT are located to $PATH but I still get problems with 'make'.

Here you can see where CD-HIT files are located.

```
$ pwd
/home/Ale/cdhit-4.8.1
```

The path is in $PATH

```
$ $PATH
-bash: /home/Ale/cdhit-4.8.1:/home/Ale/cdhit-4.8.1:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

When using make it shows this error.

```
$ make -f Makefile
g++  -fopenmp -DWITH_ZLIB -O2  cdhit-common.c++ -c
make: g++: No se encontró el programa
make: *** [Makefile:79: cdhit-common.o] Error 127
```

Comment: What the error message says is that you do not have `g++` installed (or the shell does not know where to find it). In order to compile C++ sources you need a C++ compiler (this is what `g++` is). You can check this by typing `g++ --version`. Note: to display the value of your `PATH` environment variable you should not just type `$PATH` but `echo $PATH`.